# Image isn't showing up - Tkinter

Tags: python, image, oop, user-interface, tkinter

I'm facing a problem regarding displaying a selected image on GUI. When I run the two functions `display()` & `fileopen()` separately it works just fine (meaning the image appears) however when I place the two functions within the class `PageFive`, for some reason it doesn't. Does anyone have any idea why that is?

```
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #Setup Menu
        MainMenu(self)
        #Setup Frame
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree, PageFour,PageFive):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)  
    def show_frame(self, context):
        frame = self.frames[context]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg= '#e6e6e6')
        
              

        #instructions
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Criminal Identification System", font=("orbitron", 35, 'bold'), bg='#e6e6e6')
        label.pack(pady=100,padx=100)

        page_one = Button(self, text="Sign Up", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageOne), font=("Raleway",12 ,'bold'), bg="darkturquoise", fg="#0096aa", height=2, width=15)
        page_one.pack()
        page_two = Button(self, text="Sign In", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageTwo), font=("Raleway",12 ,'bold'), bg="darkturquoise", fg="#0096aa", height=2, width=15)
        page_two.pack()
        about_us = Button(self, text="About us", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageThree), font=("Raleway",12 ,'bold'), bg="darkturquoise", fg="#0096aa", height=2, width=15)
        about_us.pack(pady=0,padx=10)
        contact_us = Button(self, text="Contact us", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageFour), font=("Raleway",12 ,'bold'), bg="darkturquoise", fg="#0096aa", height=2, width=15)
        contact_us.pack(pady=0,padx=5)
        upload = Button(self, text="Upload", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageFive), font=("Raleway",12 ,'bold'), bg="darkturquoise", fg="#0096aa", height=2, width=15)
        upload.pack(pady=0,padx=5)
        


class PageFive(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg= '#e6e6e6')
        
        def display():
            img,panel = fileopen()
            # set the image as img  
            panel.image = img 
            panel.pack()

        def fileopen():
            global img
            
            # Select the Imagename  from a folder  
            filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title ='open', filetypes=(("PNGs", "*.png"),("JPGs", "*.jpg"), ("GIFs", "*.gif")))
            # opens the image 
            img = Image.open(filename) 

            # resize the image and apply a high-quality down sampling filter 
    #       img = img.resize((700, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
            # PhotoImage class is used to add image to widgets, icons etc 
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) 
            # create a label 
            panel = Label(image = img) 
            return img, panel
        
        self.button1=Button(self, text = "Browse Input Image",fg = "Black", padx=5, pady=5, bd=4, command =display)
        self.button1.pack(side= 'bottom')
        self.exitbutton=Button(self, text = "Exit",fg = "Black", padx=5, pady=5, bd=4, command =lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        self.exitbutton.pack(side= 'bottom')
```

Comment: After keeping only `PageFive` related stuff, your code works fine.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "related stuff"? I tried it multiple times and it still won't work.

Comment: See [here](https://pastebin.com/cCEhAPAF) for a cut-down version with `PageFive` related stuff only that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `fileopen()`, you will need to call `self.fileopen()` since this is now an attribute of the class `PageFive` and you should have the parameter `self` in the `fileopen` function like so `fileopen(self)`.

Also, an advantage of using OOP is to avoid the use of global variables, a better way to put your code could be something like this

```py
def display(self):
    self.fileopen()
    self.panel.pack()

def fileopen(self):
    # Select the Imagename  from a folder  
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title ='open', filetypes=(("PNGs", "*.png"),("JPGs", "*.jpg"), ("GIFs", "*.gif")))
    # opens the image 
    self.img = Image.open(filename) 

    # resize the image and apply a high-quality down sampling filter 
    # img = img.resize((700, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
    # PhotoImage class is used to add image to widgets, icons etc 
    self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img) 
    # create a label 
    self.panel = Label(image = self.img) 
    self.panel.image = self.img
```

**EDIT**

> even when it displays an image, the image tends to appear outside the frame.

I believe this should solve that, since now you are specifying the frame as its parent.

```py
self.panel = Label(self,image = self.img)
```

**UPDATE**

Having closely rechecked your codes, I have found couple of other issues as well, refer to the updated code below (I have removed certain lines due to unavailability)

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

class PageFive(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg= '#e6e6e6')
        self.pack()
        self.button1=Button(self, text = "Browse Input Image",fg = "Black", padx=5, pady=5, bd=4, command =self.display)
        self.button1.pack(side= 'bottom')
        
    def display(self):
        self.fileopen()
        self.panel.pack()

    def fileopen(self):
        # Select the Imagename  from a folder  
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title ='open', filetypes=(("PNGs", "*.png"),("JPGs", "*.jpg"), ("GIFs", "*.gif")))
        # opens the image 
        self.img = Image.open(filename) 
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img) 
        # create a label 
        self.panel = Label(self,image = self.img) 
        self.panel.image = self.img

root=Tk()
PageFive(root,None)
root.mainloop()
```

You hadn't packed the frame, also I don't see the point in placing the browse button after the asking for the file, it would be better to put it in the initialization.

Comment: Thank you for you time, but i tried this solution and it's still not working! Am i doing something wrong in classes App() and StartPage()? Because even when it displays an image, the image tends to appear outside the frame.

Comment: If anything is moving/appearing outside a particular widget means that you haven't specified the parent correctly. I can see that the label `panel` does not have a parent specified so it will go ahead and assume the root.

Comment: Well i did exactly that, and now it doesn't even open the file dialog window when i run the code (with all classes). Did it actually work for you?

Comment: @Sam I have updated the answer, that works for me, hope it was helpful.

Comment: Yes i can see why it wasn't working, but now it works perfectly, thank you very much for your help!